# CSS background-image not working with Spring Boot application

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-boot

I read so many posts about this issue but I just couldn't solve it. I am trying to add a simple background image in my html page as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url(../static/background.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the Spring application and went to `localhost:8080/temp`, I gotta see my html page which I set in my controller as get request but all I got is just a white blank page. The thing is, if I manually right click my `temp.html` file and open it in chrome, it works just fine, I can see my image. So I think there is a problem with spring boot or something?

Here's my resources directory:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who struggle with this, if you are using Spring Security dependency, give permission to your files like this:

[image]

Then put your image under the static/img folder like this:

[image]

Put the CSS into your CSS file:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Lastly, add CSS link to your HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/register.css}">
```

Hope this helps to someone!

Answer (score 1):

Resources in `resources/static` are mapped to the root, `/`. Templates are also mapped to the root, `/`. That's why the reference in the template should be `background.jpg`.

Comment: You mean like this sir?
background-image: url(/background.jpg);
That didn't work either.

Comment: Now you use wrong syntax. It should be `url("background.jpg");`.

Comment: Unfortunately sir, that did not work too.

Comment: I solved it sir. I guess it was because i'm using Spring Security. I posted an answer, can you check it?

Comment: @covenant: It was not only because of security. You used "/static" in the path and that was not correct. "/static" is mapped to the root, "/", and should not be present in the path. Now you correctly removed it from the path.